# Way to pass a script as a docker build argument?

Tags: shell, docker

I want to pass a multi-line script as a argument to docker build command, something like that:

```
docker build -t tertparam --build-arg load_cat_agent=true --build-arg deploy_cat_script='
echo "aaa";
echo "bbb"
' --no-cache .
```

and execute it during build, my Dockerfile is like

```
FROM python:3-alpine

ARG load_cat_agent
ARG deploy_cat_script

ADD . /root/
WORKDIR /root/

RUN if [ $load_cat_agent == "true" ]; then \
         $deploy_cat_script;\
    fi
    CMD /root/start.sh && /root/wait.sh
```

but i found that it always just print

```
Step 6/7 : RUN if [ $load_cat_agent == "true" ]; then    $deploy_cat_script;    fi
 ---> Running in 7868c310e8e5

"aaa" echo "bbb"
```

how can i do that?

Comment: the script should be in the docker image using Copy , then you need only to use load_cat_agent=true

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write the build args to shell script and then run the shell script.

```
FROM python:3-alpine

ARG load_cat_agent
ARG deploy_cat_script

ADD . /root/
WORKDIR /root/
RUN echo $deploy_cat_script > ./deploy_cat_script.sh
RUN chmod +x ./deploy_cat_script.sh
RUN if [ $load_cat_agent == "true" ]; then \
          ./deploy_cat_script.sh;\
    fi
CMD /root/start.sh && /root/wait.sh
```

output:

```
Step 8/9 : RUN if [ $load_cat_agent == "true" ]; then           ./deploy_cat_script.sh;    fi
 ---> Running in 08a2f528a14d
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two images that are so different that the commands you need to build them are different, it's better to just have two separate Dockerfiles.  The `docker build -f` command can specify which Dockerfile to use, and the Docker Compose `build:` block has a similar `dockerfile:` option.

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /root/
ADD . ./
CMD ["/root/start.sh"]
```

```sh
# Dockerfile.deploy
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /root/
ADD . ./
RUN echo "aaa" \
 && echo "bbb"
CMD ["/root/start.sh"]
```

If you don't mind needing to run `docker build` multiple times, you can have one image be built `FROM` the other.  It will inherit its filesystem and metadata settings like the default CMD.

```sh
# Dockerfile.deploy, version 2
FROM tertparam
RUN echo "aaa" \
 && echo "bbb"
```

```sh
docker build -t tertparam .
docker build -t tertparam-deploy -f Dockerfile.deploy .
```

In your original example you might be able to get away with [`eval`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_19) the string, but that setup is complex enough that you'll need to script it anyways, so the Dockerfile-based approach probably isn't any more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `$deploy_cat_script` is that shell expansions are detecting command separators before variable expansions. One solution is to use `eval`. Make sure to learn about [eval command and security issues associated with it](Eval command and security issues).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
ARG load_cat_agent
ARG deploy_cat_script
RUN set -x && if [ "$load_cat_agent" == "true" ]; then \
         eval "$deploy_cat_script"; \
    fi
```

With something more complicated such as `deploy_cat_script='for i in a b c; do echo $i | sed "s/^/test: /"; done'` executes like so:

```
$ docker build -t tertparam --build-arg load_cat_agent=true --build-arg deploy_cat_script='for i in a b c; do echo $i | sed "s/^/test: /"; done' .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.168kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:3-alpine
 ---> 59acf2b3028c
Step 2/4 : ARG load_cat_agent
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6e383d31f589
Step 3/4 : ARG deploy_cat_script
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 04fc43723e0f
Step 4/4 : RUN set -x && if [ "$load_cat_agent" == "true" ]; then          eval "$deploy_cat_script";     fi
 ---> Running in 72e46c08072e
+ '[' true '==' true ]
+ eval 'for i in a b c; do echo $i | sed "s/^/test: /"; done'
test: a
+ echo a
+ sed 's/^/test: /'
+ sed 's/^/test: /'
+ echo b
test: b
+ sed 's/^/test: /'
+ echo c
test: c
Removing intermediate container 72e46c08072e
 ---> 765de7cf22a1
Successfully built 765de7cf22a1
Successfully tagged tertparam:latest
```